# sequelize sync options.force = true crashs when dropping table that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm developing an aplication using nodejs + sequelize. I read the documentation of sequelize (which isn't great...) and since I'm in development environment I want to drop the tables before a new execution, so, this is the code

```
sequelize.sync({
  force: true,
  logging: console.log
  }).then(function(){});
```

If there are no tables in the database it produces an exception, which I think it should not

> Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "vouchers" CASCADE;
>   Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: must be owner of relation vouchers
>       at Query.formatError

If I already had the tables, then it tries to drop the last table twice, which repeats the exception

> Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "vouchers" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "requestline" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "requests" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "products" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "blacklists" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "costumer" CASCADE;
>   Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "costumer" CASCADE;
>   Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: must be owner of relation
>   costumer
>       at Query.formatError

Can't understand why...
So, I worked around it like this

```
//workaround
sequelize.sync({
  force: true,
  logging: console.log
})
  .then(function () { })
  .catch(function (err) {
    sequelize.sync({
      logging: console.log
    }).then(function () { })
  })
```

Which indeed works, but it's ugly...
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Error "must be owner of relation vouchers" indicates permissions issue. Fix isn't really a fix since it's probably avoiding the delete operation. See if the connected user have required perms on the database.

Comment: Well, that doesn't explain why when the tables already exist, it drops them, then tries to re-drop one and gives the exactly same exception, I don't believe that is the reason. Do you have an idea of how to know that for sure?

Comment: You can check users and database permissions executing postgres CLI statements in the terminal:  `psql database_name -c '\du'`, `psql database_name -c '\l'` and `psql database_name -c '\dt'`. See if your target user has correct permissions before and after the database is setup.